# How to check if a style property is set or not?

Tags: c#, webforms

I can set a label in code behind to be underlined

```
Label1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
```

But how can I check if a Label is underlined or not? Something like this?

```
if(Label1.Style.Add("text-decoration") == "underline")
if(Label1.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextDecoration] == "underline")
```

Both do not work!

Comment: Is this webforms?  Please provide more context. How and where is this code used?

Comment: How about `Label1.Style["text-decoration"] == "underline"`?

Comment: I'm presuming MVVM here, but you should be setting styles based on the view model, not using code behind to set styles and then checking against them.

Comment: Sorry, for not describing enough. I'm doing web applications and D Stanley had the correct solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test a certain style and your using web forms I recommend checking the data attribute of that specific style. D Stanley above gave the following code snippet that would work to check for a Boolean value.

```
Label1.Style["text-decoration"] == "underline"
```